# Matar .exe en un servicio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Muy buenas tardes ,
tengo 5 servicios Windows que realizan lo mismo cada uno (Generar PDF al consumir un .exe vb6) cada uno de los servicios tiene su propio usuario.

el problema que tengo es el siguiente cuando hay problemas con el .exe se queda pegado el servicio( no avanza los demás procesos y eso pasa a los 5). entonces tengo que ingresar a  borrar el  .exe que se genera en el administrador de tareas y reiniciar los servicio.

habrá una forma de que cuando el .exe se quede pegado, siga su proceso el servicio

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una situación donde a veces Word no termina correctamente.  Tuve que crear un programa arrancado cada 15 minutos por Windows Task Schedule.  Busca WINWORD.EXE y para cada que arranca más de 15 minutes, lo termina.  El código (en parte):

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD");
Process[] array = processesByName;
int termindos = 0;
foreach (Process process in array)
{
    if (process.StartTime.AddMinutes(num) <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(text, append: true))
        {
            streamWriter.WriteLine("PID " + process.Id + " arrancado " + process.StartTime.ToLongDateString() + " a " + process.StartTime.ToShortTimeString() + " terminado " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        }
        process.Kill();
        terminados++;
    }
}
```

num es integer para cuantos minutos.  Espero que lo ayude.